# Problems encountered in using WIC (Windows imaging component)

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, wic

Recently, I used WIC to parse GIF. The code was written, and it can run perfectly on win10 and win7, but it failed on WinXP. I ruled it out for a long time, and finally found the reason on this line of code:

```
// pBitmapFrameDecode is an IWICBitmapFrameDecode
hr = pBitmapFrameDecode->GetMetadataQueryReader(&pFrameMetadataQueryReader);
if (hr == WINCODEC_ERR_UNSUPPORTEDOPERATION) MessageBoxA(NULL, "WINCODEC_ERR_UNSUPPORTEDOPERATION", "Error!", MB_OK);
```

In this line of code, `GetMetadataQueryReader` failed, it causes `GetMetadataByName` to fail in the following code. I felt very strange, so I checked out MSDN.
[IWICBitmapFrameDecode::GetMetadataQueryReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wincodec/nf-wincodec-iwicbitmapframedecode-getmetadataqueryreader)

But I found that my XP computer meets the minimum configuration requirements (SP3) written in MSDN. What's more strange is that the function returns `WINCODEC_ERR_UNSUPPORTEDOPERATION`. It's so weird. At first, I thought it was my own device problem, so I borrowed a few XP computers and run my code on them. They all return `WINCODEC_ERR_UNSUPPORTEDOPERATION`. Is MSDN wrong?

Comment: We can't see the CoInitializeEx() call.  It matters a lot, WIC became free-threaded at Win7.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Stop writing code for XP. Let it die.

Answer (score 6):

MSDN is not "wrong", but somewhat incomplete.

Most of WIC is often just an intermediary between your code and the decoder/encoders (codecs, specific for a given file format).

The fact GetMetadataQueryReader is supported on XP doesn't mean a given codec on XP supports the metadata with the same level as the same codec on other Windows versions. Images metadata can be quite complex and deep (and specifications can be improved in time).

If you go to this MSDN page: [What's new for Windows 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wic/what-s-new-in-wic-for-windows-8-1#whats-new-for-windows-7) you'll read this:

> Extended Metadata Support for JPEG, PNG, and GIF:
>
> In Windows 7, WIC has extended its metadata support for JPEG, PNG, and
> GIF images.
>
> - Added support for animated GIF and GIF properties.

So it probably means you're touching GIF files that have unsupported metadata properties, for which support was added post-XP (Vista or 7).